# Want to set 'from' in mail

Tags: apex

I am sending mail from my batch class to given mail Ids using SingleEmailMessage instance and methods. I am setting up setSenderDisplayName to 'test'. After sending that mail, In mail for
**From - test** showing like that. but I don't want to show email Id. Or receiving mailer can not reply for the same mail. Anyone know how should I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking how to set the "reply to" address for SingleEmailMessage that you send out?

Use the setReplyTo method

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
// Specify the address used when the recipients reply to the email. 
mail.setReplyTo('support@acme.com');
// Specify the from name displayed in the recipients mail client
mail.setSenderDisplayName('User4534');
```

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_Messaging_SingleEmailMessage_instance_methods.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fapex_Messaging_SingleEmailMessage_instance_methods.htm|SkinName=webhelp